# When are mission rewards determined?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

I wonder, when are the rewards for missions determined exactly? I've noticed that if I reload before Guerilla Ops appear, I seem to always get the same proposed rewards. Even if I reload before supply drop and fast forward to that GOp - still the same rewards. Is it set for the whole game at the start?